# Custom class decorator for a @Component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple component class:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './simple-text-viewer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./simple-text-viewer.component.scss'],
})
export class SimpleTextViewerComponent extends BaseComponent {
}
```

I would like to create a decorator for this class to apply some default behaviour using other Angular's decorators e.g. `@HostBinding` or `HostListener` like follows:

```
export function WithDefaultStyles() {
    return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): any>(Base: T) {
        @Component({template: ''})
        class Mixin extends Base {

            @HostBinding('style')
            hostStyles: { [key: string]: string } = {};

            @HostListener('mouseover')
            onMouseOver() {
                this.hostStyles['color'] = 'red';
            }

        }

        return Mixin;
    }
}
```

As a result I want to use it like that:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './simple-text-viewer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./simple-text-viewer.component.scss'],
})
@WithDefaultStyles() // here is my decorator
export class SimpleTextViewerComponent extends BaseComponent {
}
```

I have tried to remove `@Component({template: ''})` from the `Mixin` class but then the Angular's compiler complains that I can't use `@HostBinding` and `@HostListener`. I also tried to replace `@Component({template: ''})` into `@Directive()` but then I get error that directive cannot extend component.

With the code I posted, the outcome is that the original template `./simple-text-viewer.component.html` is ignored and `@Component({template: ''})` is used instead to render an empty string.

Is there a way to implement it like I explained with that difference the original `@Component` is not "erased" by the mixin?

Comment: Can you not simply remove the @Component..?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, when I remove it from Mixin I can't use HostBinding and HostListener

Comment: I don't think adding decorators via class decorator is possible. Here someone has attempted something similar in nature (though, they also reverted to adding `window.listener`) https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926893/15439733